# Can't change my header color

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple code on my website to change the header background color once a user scrolls, but it doesn't work, I don't know why...

This is the CSS

```
.changeHeaderColor {
background: white !important;
border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
border-color: #660EBE;
transition: 0.5s all;
}
```

And this is the javascript

```
$(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {
     $('.elementor-element-93f89f2').addClass('changeHeaderColor');
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 50) {
     $('.elementor-element-93f89f2').removeClass('changeHeaderColor');
  }
   });
});
```

You can check the source-code in this page: http://www.alessandrodiruscio.com/ux-senior-designer/

Thanks a lot for the help!

Alessandro

Comment: The main problem comes from the library jQuery, you're getting `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` in your page, try to include jQuery...

Comment: As @ZakariaAcharki stated, you need to include jQuery into your site like this: (e. g. in the `head`) `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>`

Comment: I've added the line for jquery, but nothing changed.

Answer (score -1):

Try with the *pageYOffset*.Hope this will help you.

```
 var navbarCollapse = function() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= 50) {
             $(".elementor-element-93f89f2").addClass("changeHeaderColor");
        } else {
             $(".elementor-element-93f89f2").removeClass("changeHeaderColor");
        }
 };
 navbarCollapse();
 $(window).scroll(navbarCollapse);
```

Comment: Don't think it's about the code, cause I tried it on https://jsfiddle.net/ and it works well. Don't know why it doesn't work on my website...

Comment: I've created a similar version on jsfiddle.net that doesn't work as well. What's wrong in it? https://jsfiddle.net/thirdeyeblind82/mrnc5kw9/5/